# Creating and uploading gem on github

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

I have a written a ruby lib which I want to host on github as a gem. How to createa gem and host it on github?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best practice way of doing this nowadays is to use Bundler. There's a guide here to show you how...

http://asciicasts.com/episodes/245-new-gem-with-bundler

Answer (score 1):

Github no longer hosts gems, but as long as you include a .gemspec in the directory, it will be installable via bundler.

You can check out one of mine for ideas on how to structure it if you'd like: https://github.com/ehowe/ruby-ipmitool

Answer (score 1):

If it contains a `.gemspec`, you can push it to rubygems.org, [they'll help you](http://guides.rubygems.org/).